Android, Firebase.analytics is not resolved
Looking at https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=android we can set up Firebase Analytics.
dependencies {
    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.2.0"))

    // Add the dependency for the Analytics library
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
}

Then in MainActivity:
private lateinit var firebaseAnalytics: FirebaseAnalytics

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // Obtain the FirebaseAnalytics instance.
    firebaseAnalytics = Firebase.analytics
}

But Firebase.analytics is not resolved.

Instead of implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics") use implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx")
Or, maybe set firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).
